# Generate Objective-C Framework from .NET Standard Project using Embeddinator 4000 on Windows

Tags: c#, xamarin, embeddinator

I have a current Xcode iPhone project that I would like to switch over to Xamarin so that I can support iOS and Android with a single code base.  However, in the short term I don't have the time to replace the Xcode project with a Xamarin forms version.  Therefore, I have come up with a plan to build the core logic into a Xamarin solution in VS20017.  I would then use [Embeddinator-4000](https://github.com/mono/Embeddinator-4000) to generate a .framework file which I could use from my Xcode project.  In this way I can maintain the current Xcode UI project while I work on a full Xamarin replacement.

I was hoping to develop on a Windows machine, as this is what I'm most used to, but I can't seem to get embeddinator to work.

I've tried to get it to work with a Xamarin.iOS project, .NET Standard 2.0 and .NET Framework 4.6.2.  Each fails with a dependency error, given below:

- Xamarin - `Can't find the assembly 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e', referenced by 'Embed.Xamarin, Version=1.0.7015.35480, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'`
- .NET Standard - `Can't find the assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51', referenced by 'Embed.Standard, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.`
- .NET Framework - `Can't find the assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089', referenced by 'Embed.NetFX, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.  Embedded.NetFX`

I have two questions

1. Am I using a workable approach to migrate my Xcode project over to Xamarin or is there some other option, of which, I'm not aware of?  Maybe a conversion tool?
2. If this approach is workable, what do I need to do to get Embeddinator to work on a windows machine?  Is it even possible?

Comment: You would need to use Embeddinator on macOS in order to create an ObjC framework

Comment: What if i install mono on windows? Would that allow it to work or does it need some component of the mac os?